# Getting error bind variable does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

when i try to execute the following query i am getting the desired output but with error bind variable does not exist. could someone advise to fix this error

Error :

```
Error report -
ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 25
01006. 00000 -  "bind variable does not exist"
```

Query :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE

v_sql varchar2(5000);
v_sql2 varchar2(5000);
 v_prj_id varchar2(4000):='B00781728,B00781628,B00781611,A43670001';
v_event  varchar2(5000) := 'CORE_DTS_INTERNAL';

BEGIN

FOR i IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_prj_id, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
         FROM dual 
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_prj_id, ',') + 1 
) LOOP


   v_sql :=  v_sql || 'select '''|| i.l ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ' || i.l || '.SI_Recipient WHERE EVENT = ''' ||V_EVENT ||'''   UNION ALL ' || chr(10);


END LOOP;

v_sql2 :=  RTRIM(v_sql, 'UNION ALL ' || chr(10) ) ;

 Dbms_Output.Put_Line (v_sql2);

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL2 USING V_EVENT; 



  END;
 /
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove using clause and it'll be working but it isn't a good pattern. Using bind variables is better choice especially for security reasons. You can just change your declaration of v_sql and leave rest of code as it is.

```
v_sql :=  v_sql || 'select '''|| i.l ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ' || i.l || '.SI_Recipient WHERE EVENT = :V_EVENT   UNION ALL ' || chr(10);
```

EDIT:
As somebody has ponted out in comment to other answer my solution would only work without loop (or in one-time loop of course). Hard parsing is always a bad idea but in that it can't (without some writing a horrible code) be done in other way. My solution wouldn't work because you need to pass value for every bind regardless of bind's name when excuting immediate sql code.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
v_sql :=  v_sql ... WHERE EVENT = ''' ||V_EVENT ||'''   UNION ALL ...
```

to

```
v_sql :=  v_sql ... WHERE EVENT = :v_event   UNION ALL ...
```

Bind variables appear in SQL queries with a colon prefix, like `:v_event`.

Using a bind variable in this manner is better than just removing `USING V_EVENT` from your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  SQL statements that use bind variables are more scalable (fewer latches and less memory needed).

Comment: And how many variables will be needed in the using clause? Have you seen that it is in loop?

Comment: No, I hadn't noticed that.  This is a bad pattern - one schema per project.  Building dynamic queries for each set of projects of interest at a particular time is not scalable.  A separate query for every call, depending on how often the process runs, will flood the library cache and result in excessive hard parsing.  I may update my answer with a better pattern if I get time later (or you can).  In the meantime, you're right: there is no convenient way to use bind variables with a query built in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `using` clause from `execute immediate` as you are not using bind variable(`:1`) in your query which you were previously using in your query:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL2; --USING V_EVENT;
```

Comment: You are using loop and as per your previous question which I answered, using clause will require 4 times same variable.